# Change the axis of rotation when using UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm using

```
[UIView transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:]
```

with option

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
```

for a card flip, but the axis of rotation is the centre of the card. Is it possible to change that axis of rotation to the left edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using this methods. If you want to do more tricky animation, you should use CoreAnimation explicit animations with 3D transform.

[CoreAnimation programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/introduction/introduction.html)

When you'll click to change the view you'll trigger the animation and then when the animation finished you change your views with no animation.

Let's say you have two cards

```
MyCardView *cardBack;
MyCardView *cardFront;
```

The shift method should be something like that :

```
-(void)switchView {
    cardBack = [self methodToPrepareContentOfBackCard];
    [self myCustomMethodToAnimateCardWithFlip];
}
```

When the animation is complete you'll use the delegate to set :

```
    cardFront = [cardBack release];
    [cardBack release];
```